# How are directory listings generated with ratpack?

Tags: groovy, ratpack

I've just started looking at Ratpack, and my initial use case to as a simple development server.  It seems quite trivial to get it to serve a directory of static files (in Groovy), I paraphrase [this](https://danveloper.github.io/ratpack-as-a-lightweight-static-content-server.html) article:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Grab('io.ratpack:ratpack-groovy:1.5.1')
import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack

ratpack {
    handlers {
        files { dir "static" index }
    }
}
```

I see there's an option to define an index page (for example, `index.html`), but this is static. I'd like it to serve a dynamic directory listing, as Apache can.  I'd hoped this would simply require enabling a option, but I cannot find any indication such a thing exists.

I can't help feeling I have missed something. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't believe there's anything out of the box (or a config option you can turn on).  You'll need to write a handler that (based on a prefix) returns the contents of that folder

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in directory listing feature. You would have to implement your own.